# How to update Column Data Type and Length through Migration DB First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I want to update model changes in database. Actually before i have updated database with following code through migration

```
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]            
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 150, MinimumLength = 50)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
```

But now i want to update following code

```
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(maximumLength:50)]
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 150, MinimumLength = 50)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        //[Column(TypeName = "Date")]
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

but getting this error

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Date', table 'ConstructionDb.dbo.Services'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: Have you run migration after changing form `string Date` to `DateTime? Date` ?..Check  Date field in the `Services` table whether it is nullable or not.

Comment: I checked date field in services table its Allow Nulls Checked Data Type is nvarchar(MAX) this is what i want to change i want to set it not null and datetime time data type but when i run migration through command Update-Database -Verbose got the error mention above

Comment: In your model datatype is `DateTime` and in the database table it is `nvarchar(MAX)`. This is the problem. You didn't run the migration properly after changing the datatype of `Date` field. Change the datatype of the `Date` field form `nvarchar(max)` to `DataTime` in database table.

Comment: You mean i need to change nvarchar(max) to DateTime from database Design

Comment: Yes! You need to do so!

Comment: I have changed it through the design but its not saving it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177157/discussion-between-muhammad-hamza-nisar-and-tanvirarjel).